# _mm256_loadu2_m128i intrinsic not available under g++?

Tags: g++, intrinsics, avx2

I'm trying to use the AVX2 intrinsic `_mm256_loadu2_m128i`, but it seems g++ 4.8.2 doesn't have it.

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: This isn't an intrinsic I'm familiar with. What instruction does it map to?

Comment: @CoryNelson It doesn't. The Intel intrinsic guide says this: _"Note: This intrinsic creates a sequence of two or more instructions, and may perform worse than a native instruction. Consider the performance impact of this intrinsic."_

Comment: The only reference I see implements it quite simply using `VMOV`/`VINSERT`.

Comment: I don't have the intrinsics reference to hand right now, but I believe there is an _mm256_set_xxx intrinsic which is more or less equivalent.

Comment: Yeah. It's true. You can see it here: https://godbolt.org/g/EUnXSe Toggle the compiler to gcc and see it fail splendidly...

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem in GCC and Clang.  However it compiles in ICC.  You can test this with GCC, Clang, and ICC at http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Note, this is a AVX intrinsic not AVX2.  Most of the 256-bit integer load and store intrinsics only need AVX.  AVX2 provides some gather and mask loads but everything else only needs AVX.

Since Haswell can load two 128-bit values at once you can achieve the same effect as  `_mm256_loadu2_m128i` using `_mm256_inserti128_si256`.  Something like this

```
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
    int low[4];
    int high[4];
    _mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(
        _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)low)),
        _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)high),1);
}
```

Comment: clang-3.3 will generate the load + insert sequence from normal `loadu` operations when targeting avx but not avx2.

Comment: For example: http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22%2F%2F%20Type%20your%20code%20here%2C%20or%20load%20an%20example.%5Cn%5Cn%23include%20%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%5Cn%5Cn__m256d%20foo(double%20*x%2C%20__m256d%20y)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20return%20_mm256_add_pd(_mm256_loadu_pd(x)%2Cy)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fopt%2Fclang-3.3%2Fbin%2Fclang%2B%2B%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%20-mavx%22%7D%5D%7D

Comment: Slightly more concise version: `_mm256_set_m128i(_mm_loadu_si128(hi), _mm_loadu_si128(lo))`. Compiles to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Guess there is no such intrinsic named `_mm256_loadu_m128i`. All I can find with `_mm256_load` are `_mm256_load_pd`, `_mm256_load_ps`, `_mm256_load_si256`, `_mm256_loadu_pd`, `_mm256_loadu_ps`and `_mm256_loadu_si256`.
These all come with AVX and the gcc header is `immintrin.h`.

Comment: `_mm256_loadu2_m128i`, not `_mm256_loadu_m128i`. Also see [`_mm256_loadu_m128i`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_loadu2_m128i) from the Intel Intrinsic Guide.